# Autorun python file on reboot using systemd on raspbian

Tags: python, systemd

I am trying to autorun a python file on reboot using systemd. The reason I am trying to use systemd is because my python file requires the network to be connected and available at that point in time, and the /home/pi directory is required to be ready for use and the System time has been updated by NTP to proceed.
However I received following errors when I try to start the script:

```
systemctl start mysript.service
```

> Failed to start myscript.service: Unit myscript.service failed to
>   load: Invalid argument. See system logs and 'systemctl status
>   myscript.service' for details.

```
systemctl status myscript.service
```

> myscript.service
>       Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
>       Active inactive (dead)
>
> myscript.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.

Following are myscript.service:

```
[unit]
Description=MyPythonFile
After=multi-user.target

[service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/mypythonfile/file.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

do anyone have any idea why I am receiving this error?

**[[EDIT]]**
referenced this post: https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/

The service can now be loaded, however I received an error because my python program is using Tkinter.

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "0.0"
myscript.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Unit myscript.service entered failed state.
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Following this post: https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/

It appears that [unit] and [service] should have a capital in them:
so now they become - [Unit] and [Service].

This may be irrevelant but maybe change

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

to

```
/usr/bin/python
```

**EDIT**

*"I would try opening ./.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
with a text editor and add your python script with a leading '@'
@python HomeV3.py
You might need a path for your script."* - Credit to SurferTim - https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=184797

Hope this helps!

Comment: If that doesn't help - look at this: http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/auto-running-programs-gui under "Setting an application"